# HTML: Unable to scroll over iframe video embed (viemo)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm making a portfolio using wordpress. In it I have embedded a Vimeo video with a play button in my portfolio using the attached code, unfortunately, I'm not able to scroll when the mouse is over the iframe section. The only possible workaround I found so far is to set the z-index to -1 but that is not helping me as the play button becomes unclickable.

```
<figure class="wp-block-vimeo-create vimeo-create__video-container">
    <div style="width:100%">
        
        <iframe class="vimeo-core-video" loading="lazy" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/654636998?autoplay=false&amp;autopause=true&amp;loop=true&amp;background=false&amp;controls=true&amp;muted=false&amp;byline=false&amp;portrait=false&amp;title=false&amp;transparent=false&amp;pip=false&amp;dnt=true&amp;playsinline=true&amp;speed=false" width="2732" height="1162" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen scrolling style="max-width:100%;width:100%;height:100%;aspect-ratio:2732 / 1162">
            
        </iframe></div>

</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce the problem you are describing as I tried it in an editor and did not encounter any problems with the scroll.
I guess as it is wordpress something else will be to blame.
Can you give us more information eg in which browser this happens etc.

Comment: Chrome, Firefox, safari all latest versions, moreover it does not even take touch feedback when view the website on mobile devices (both ios, android)

Comment: I'm trying to duplicate the problem. Can you send me the actual link where you implement the iframe?